# Defining which parts my module I'm responsible for, and which ones the user should take care

Tags: node.js, request

I'm creating a simple wrapper of my endpoints using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, and one of my endpoints is used to upload files and a JSON, for that, i'm using `multipart/form-data`:

```
function doSomething(files, theJSON) {
  request.post('https://m.com/endpoint', {
    formData: {
      files,
      theJSON
    }
  })
}
```

But I'm with a doubt about the responsibility of providing the right arguments.

The files must be a array of read streams, and the theJSON, must be a json. I have two options, here:

1- Parse the args:

```
function doSomething(files, theJSON) {
  request.post('https://m.com/endpoint', {
    formData: {
      files: files.map(file => fs.createReadStream(file),
      theJSON: JSON.stringify(theJSON)
    }
  })
}
```

2- Let the user be responsible for the right type.

Which one would be the best one?? Is there a right choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Whatever you do, document it.

---

There is some precedent for providing short-cuts for very common tasks, like uploading a file.  In this case, you can conditionally check for strings and treat it as a path, otherwise assume it is a stream:

```
files: files.map(file =>
    typeof file === 'string' ?
    fs.createReadStream(file) :
    file
)
```